# Delete from mysql via url query. Error "Query was empty"

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to delete something from database using this url:

```
siteurl.com/mail.php?action=delete&mail_id=10
```

with this code:

```
if ($action == delete) { 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) { 
        $deleteid = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM mail WHERE mail_id = ".$deleteid." LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);      
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].' ');
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

But its not working, its showing the error: `Query was empty`

Whats wrong?

Comment: i belive u got a typo here :: $deleteid = $_GET['mail_id'];

Comment: $action = $_GET['action']; $deteleid = $_GET['mail_id'];  if ($action == "delete")

Comment: Also, unless you set a constant prior with `define('delete','delete')` any value submitted by the GET method is actually a string, which needs to be wrapped in quotes (unless numeric) like in `if($_GET['action'] == 'delete') {}`

Answer (score 2):

Did you get the action? Instead of get id, you should get the mail id.

```
$_GET['action']  
$_GET['mail_id']
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mail_id` in the URL but `id` in your PHP code. Use the same one in both places and it will work.

However, and this is very important, your code as written has a huge security problem known as SQL injection. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, so learn how to use `mysqli_*` and/or `PDO` instead, and use prepared statements with them so that it will be much less likely that you will be subject to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: +1 for the important SQL injection note.

Answer (score 0):

In your query string you are passing the variable name as `mail_id` but while retrieving you are using just `id`. You have to use `mail_id` and also you are not  retrieving  the `action` variable value. You should use `$_GET['action'] == delete` instead of this  `$action == delete`. So finally your code should be like this

```
if ($_GET['action'] == delete) { 
    if(isset($_GET['mail_id'])) { 
        $deleteid = $_GET['mail_id'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM mail WHERE mail_id = ".$deleteid." LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);      
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].' ');
        exit(); 
    }
}
```